# LINQ to Entities - get amount of functions for every (role, function group)

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am new to Linq to Entities, and have no idea how to make one query.

My models are:

```
public class Role 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }   

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<AppFunction> AppFunctions { get; set; }
}


public class AppFunction 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; private set; }

    public ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

So I have roles and application functions. Each role can have a lot of associated application functions, and each application function can be associated with a lot of roles. So it's just MANY-TO-MANY between roles and application functions.

And there is one nuance:
If `AppFunction.ParentId == null` - I treat as a category.

Otherwise it's a concrete function, that belongs to one of the categories.

I am not sure if it's a good example of architecture, but it's so in my app for now.

And I want to make such a query, that will return data for the next ViewModel:

```
public class RoleCategoryViewModel
{
    public string RoleName { get; set; }

    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

To make things clear:

```
              Role1    Role 2

Category 1    (3/7)    (0/7)    

Category 2    (1/2)    (2/2)

Category 3    (3/5)    (4/5)
```

That's a table I wanna show to user on the page. It's matrix for roles and functions categories. At the intersection of role X and category Y there is an amount of application functions from category Y that associated with role X.

For example, (3/7) at intersection of "Role 1" and "Category 1" means that "Category 1" contains 7 "subfunctions" at all and there are only 3 function from "Category 1" that associated with "Role 1".

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we need to make some changes to your ViewModel like this:

```
public class RoleCategoryViewModel
{
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public int RoleCount { get; set; }
    public int TotalRolesCount { get; set; }
}
```

then here is the Query :

```
        var list = (from category in context.AppFunctions.Where(m => m.ParentId == null)
                   from role in category.Roles
                   select new RoleCategoryViewModel
                              {
                                      CategoryName = category.Name,
                                      RoleCount = role.AppFunctions.Count,
                                      TotalRolesCount = category.Roles.Count,
                                      RoleName = role.Name,
                              }).ToList();
```